# Draw canvas in flutter

Tags: flutter, canvas, custom-painting

I am using `drawDRRect` for drawing rectangle, and want that inner color will be `Colors.green` and outer color `Colors.blue` how can I control `Paint()`?

```
 canvas.drawDRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
            Rect.fromLTWH(
              0,
              0,
              context.size.width,
              36,
            ),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
            topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
            Rect.fromLTRB(canvasStartPosition.dx, 0, canvasEndPosition.dx, 0)),
        Paint()..color = Colors.green);
```

Comment: you cannot do that in one `Canvas.draw*` method call

Comment: ok thanks, you help me to find my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromLTRB(
            0,
            0,
            canvasStartPosition.dx,
            36,
          ),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        ),
        new Paint()..color = Colors.blue);
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromLTRB(
            canvasStartPosition.dx,
            0,
            canvasEndPosition.dx,
            36,
          ),
        ),
        new Paint()..color = Colors.green);
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromLTRB(
            canvasEndPosition.dx,
            0,
            context.size.width,
            36,
          ),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        ),
        new Paint()..color = Colors.blue);
```